# How can I navgate to the previous page while passing the state of the current page to it using react router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I know that I can use `navigate(-1)`  from the `useNavigate()` hook, to navigate to a previous page, but using `navigate(-1,{state:state})` doesn't seem to work, as I get a null value when I go to the previous page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`navigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) function has two function signatures, one takes `to` and `options` args, the other takes a single `delta` arg. When doing a delta navigation no state is passed, you are simply "moving" forward or backward through the history stack.

> ```
> declare function useNavigate(): NavigateFunction;
>
> interface NavigateFunction {
>   (
>     to: To,
>     options?: {
>       replace?: boolean;
>       state?: any;
>       relative?: RelativeRoutingType;
>     }
>   ): void;
>   (delta: number): void;
> }
> ```

### Suggested Solution

From the "previous" page you can navigate forward and pass a "referrer" value in state that the "current" page checks. If a `state.referrer` exists, use it to issue a navigation action and pass along any state, otherwise issue the delta navigation back to whatever previous page the user was on.

Previous page:

```
<Link to="/next-page" state={{ referrer: "/this-page" }}>
  Next page
</Link>
```

```
navigate("/next-page", { state: { referrer: "/this-page" } });
```

Next page:

```js
const { state } = useLocation();

...

if (state.referrer) {
  navigate(state.referrer, { state: { /* state you want to pass back */ } });
} else {
  navigate(-1);
}
```